# Is there a infinite loop in my codes? in ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

I want to get the sum of function f(i) values when i is equal from a to b
= f(a)+f(a+1)+...+f(b-1)+f(b)
So I wrote code like this.

```
let rec sigma : (int -> int) -> int -> int -> int
= fun f a b ->
if a=b then f a
else f b  + sigma f a b-1 ;;
```

but result is that there is stack overflow during evaluation. Is there a infinite loop? and why?

Answer (score 3):

`sigma f a b-1` is parsed as `(sigma f a b) - 1` instead of your intention, `sigma f a (b-1)`.  Since `sigma f a b` calls `sigma f a b` recursively in your code, it never stops.

The best practice is to put white spaces around binary operators like `sigma f a b - 1` so that you would not misread what you write.

Comment: BTW we have received the same question 4 times already in this week.  We should alarm the teachers or TAs of the course.  Is it OCaml MOOC?

Comment: Thank you for kind answer and very sorry for not being able to search questions. and It's not MOOC.

Comment: Sorry if my comment sounded blaming you.  It was not my intention.  My point is that OCaml teachers or tutors should point this syntactic glitch at classes, since it seems to be a common pitfall.

Comment: I definitely recommend using parenthesis around operations that you would like to take precendence, i.e. the `(b-1)`.